# HttpContext.Current.Session throwing Object reference error in server not in local

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session

In a Authorizaiton class I am assigning user object to session

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.SessionActiveUserInfo] = userInfo;
```

It is working fine in local but in server it is throwing

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

when I hit url with controller/actionmethod name it is throwing HTTP Error 500 ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") because of session.
Then if I hit the url again, it is working fine.

Why it is behaving like this? Any help?

Comment: What is `Constants.SessionActiveUserInfo`?

Comment: Session name getting it from Constants class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered an issue within Model View Controller, where the Session wasn't instantiated.  The problem I believe you're encountering, is that the Session doesn't actually reside on the server when you navigate to that Controller.

Below, rather than call the Session directly, I would call `SessionModify<Example>("Sample", example);` if it exist, will assign value, if not it will add the Session.

I created a class to help managing the Session:

```
public static class Storage
{
     public static void SessionAdd<T>(string label, T value)
     {
          if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(label))
               HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(label, value);
     }

     public static void SessionModify<T>(string label, T value)
     {
          if(HttpContext.Current.Session[label] != null)
          {
               HttpContext.Current.Session[label] = value;
               return;
          }

          SessionAdd(label, value);              
     }

     public static T SessionModifyAndReturn<T>(string label, T value) where T : class, new()
     {
          var content = new  T();
          if(HttpContext.Current.Session[label] != null)
               HttpContext.Current.Session[label] = value;
          else { SessionAdd(label, value); }

          content = value;
          return content;
     }           
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me implement the same